# Reference request: Time and proofs of shared pasts

Tags: reference-request, computer-science, order-theory, it.information-theory, cryptography

Is there research about structures for notions of time with distributed systems of information, as with blockchains?

I am thinking of tuples $(I, T, P, A, \prec, s, \eta, u)$ where

- $I$, $T$ and $P$ are sets that can be interpreted as *information*, *time*, and *proofs*.
- $A$ is a subset of $I\times T\times P$ where $(i, t, p)\in A$ can be interpreted as  as *"$p$ proves that the piece of information $i$ existed after $t$"*.
- $\prec$ is a relation on $T$ where $t1 \prec t2$ can be interpeted as *"$t1$ was before $t2$"*, without requiring that this does is a linear order or even an order at all.
- $s: T\times T\to T$ can be interpreted as “shared past” and satisfies $t_1 \prec s(t_1, t_2)$ and $t_2 \prec s(t_1, t_2)$ for any $t_1, t_2\in T$.
- $\eta:I\times T\to A$ can be interpreted as “instantiation”.
- (Most importantly:) $u: A\times A \to P$ can be interpreted as an “update map” such that $$e(a,b):=(i_a, s(t_a, t_b), u(a,
     b))\in A$$ for any $a, b\in A$. Here, we denoted the respective projections with $i_{*}:=\pi_I$ and $t_{*}:=\pi_T$.

**Motivation:** One interpretation of the combined map $e:A\times A\to A$ would be of two space-travellers meeting and exchanging information about their past: The triple $(i, t, p)$ might in this scenario consist of some arbitrary string $i$, some "time-hash" $t$ and a cryptographic proof $p$ that the traveler instantiated $i$ after $t$.

This leads to a lot of questions which I find interesting, e.g.:

- Under the assumption that $\eta$ is somehow useful (for example injective): Can $\prec$ be a quasiorder without it being a full relation?
- If there's a surjective map $\rho: A\to I$ and $\prec$ is a suitably nice order relation, are there always fixpoints $e(-, b)$, and is $\prec$ a blob?

**Question:** What work already exists in this direction? My questions above are for motivation and context, but I’m more interested in references than answers.

Comment: this reads more like a research program, which will be difficult to elicit a useful response; perhaps you can extract a specific question, which can be answered in the brief space of the answer box?

Comment: Oh my question is more in the direction: What research on topics like this already exists? I'll update the post accordingly.

Comment: The question(s) seems, after all, to be about sets, orders and relations (there is no other mathematical structure relevant apparently). So I think the proper tag should be logic or something similar, definitely not mathematical-physics.

Comment: @Overflowian Thanks. I adjusted the tags. (One of the questions this kind of thing could be used for would be about what the limitations of distributed consensus protocols at very large distances are. That's why I added the tag.)

Comment: I edited this to make it a clearer research request, and to remove phrases like “we interpret” (since we may or may not want to use a particular interpretation) and “can we require” (for which the answer is always yes, and the question is what follows). Also I deleted a couple examples that I found unclear, since the post is already long for a reference request.

Comment: I find the idea of a quasi-order being a partial relation troubling. The idea of a partial relation itself is troubling.  I may have fallen prey to mereological essentialism here but I think a strong case could be made that the axiom of comprehension is at stake.